# How long to put Silica gel in microwave oven?

Tags: water, microwaves

I have a 800 W microwave oven and want to dry some silica gel packages (each labeled with 10 g and sealed in paper mantling).

The silica gel is colorless and seems to be of the kind of silica gels that does not change its color when getting wet / dry.

I found the quote to have silica gel dried at around 120 °C if using a conventional oven.

Additionally the time to keep the microwave oven on depends from the amount of food and how much energy should be transferred into the food.

Weighting one (wet) sample package shows a weight of 12 g.

Apart from weighting the packages during the heating process to see whether they are dry enough (I found a source in the internet that silica gel is able to absorb as much as 20 percent of its weight): how would I calculate how long the microwave oven has to be switched on with full power for e.g. 10 packages?

I especially want to avoid that the paper sealing of the packages starts to burn if the microwave oven is on too long.

Comment: Have you tried heating it? I would try a small sample, and I would be prepared for the possibility that silica gel, even when hydrated, might not absorb any microwave energy at all.